# How can i reuse my model type properties?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api call where the response looks like:

```
export interface UserResponse {
    id: string;
    is_admin: boolean;
    last_name: string;
    phone: string;
    ...

    salary: number;
}
```

after that i am using datePipe `transform` method to trasfer my date into some different date format.But that gives string.

For example

```
 this.users[0].salary = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.users[i].salary, 'USD', 'symbol', '1.0-0');
```

Now my salary is not of type number, is of type string.

So i maked another model that indicates now the other type of User - `with salary string but not number`.

```
export interface User {
    id: string;
    is_admin: boolean;
    last_name: string;
    phone: string;
    ...

    salary: string;
}
```

But i have a lot of repeated properties inside. `id, is_admin etc`.

How can i reuse them ?

For example i will make third interface

```
export interface UserBase {
    id: string;
    is_admin: boolean;
    last_name: string;
    phone: string;
}
```

How can i insert now all properties from  `UserBase` into `User` and `UserResponse`

```
export interface User {
}
```

Comment: Consider using TypeScript union types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html like this: `salary: string | number;`

Comment: If you find my previous comment as the right solution for you then take a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/883827

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with inheritance

```
export interface User extends UserBase {
    salary: string;
}
```